# Does it make any difference using offsetof() instead of sizeof() with sockets?

Tags: c, linux, sockets

In socket programming, especially while dealing with Unix domain sockets of type `struct sockaddr_un`, some [people use](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Local-Socket-Example.html) `offsetof()` to calculate the size of the `sockaddr_un` structure like-

```
struct sockaddr_un {
    sa_family_t sun_family;               /* AF_UNIX */
    char        sun_path[108];            /* pathname */
};
size = (offsetof (struct sockaddr_un, sun_path)
          + strlen (name.sun_path));
```

In some [other places](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/unix.7.html), they use

```
size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)
```

I understand that the first method accounts for shorter path names and the second gives a fixed max size irrespective of the actual path length.

Does it really make a difference to a function like `bind` which is passed this value? If not, can these 2 be used interchangeably?

Comment: The docs in the second link say `size` needs to be at least large enough to include the null terminator, so the code in the first example needs a `+1`.

Comment: Are `sockaddr_un` and `sockaddr_in` intended to be spelled differently, or is one of them a typo?

Comment: @Keith Thompson. I meant un, not in. Corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

**offsetof** takes into account any padding that the C compiler may have added after the size of the base members. However, if you define network packets using C structures that contain padding added by the C compiler, you have bigger problems! In fact I'd ensure that a test case was added which ensures that both methods return the same size, to guard against incorrect compile options changing padding rules, for example.

In the context of this question, no, it doesn't make any difference to **bind**.

Comment: How does the `sizeof` version not account for padding? Also note that these `struct`s are not meant to be sent over the socket. They *describe* the socket.

Comment: Because in general, the minimum padding required to complete the struct may be less than the padding required for a following member. For example, in old 32-bit Intel use, the struct would be padded only to 32 bits, but if you have a double, compiler options could force that offset to 64-bit padding - and offsetof will catch that case. Excessive finesse anyhow, and solving the wrong problem!

Comment: To clarify further, a struct containing only individual char members (for example) is allowed to have char alignment, but as soon as you add a member with bigger alignment, the whole struct needs that bigger alignment.

Comment: It's the `sizeof` the whole struct, not just the `sizeof` the first member. Whether you use `sizeof` or `offsetof`, the padding between the first and second members gets included.

Comment: And any padding added to the end, to align the following element in an array, is also included.

Comment: gcc (and thus also clang and possibly others) has the option `__attribute__((packed))` to add to `struct`s to enforce that the compiler won't add padding.

Answer (score 0):

I would say the `offsetof` version you posted is incorrect. It should have at least a +1 in it, as the path is defined as a null-terminated string, and that's the length that the kernel returns e.g. from `getsockname()`.

Even with the +1, I don't see the point of using something complex over something simple. It does save a few bytes being transferred to the kernel, but `bind()` and friends are hardly the rate-determine steps.